# Program Flow Structure

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

MainSub does 5 tasks. Several tasks are currently written as functions returning whether or not they are successful. I want to continue on to the next task only if the previous completed successfully, else run workerThreadComplete.

Is there a way to structure this so that MainSub is more readable, specifically removing the "If Not [] Then GoTo" piece on each line? How should something like this generally be structured?

```
Sub MainSub(params As Object) 'run by workerThread
    Dim s As sessionData = CType(params, sessionData)
    If Not verifyExcelResource(s) Then GoTo eexit
    If Not launchAS400(s) Then GoTo eexit
    If Not runLookup(s) Then GoTo eexit
    If Not payeeProcessLoop(s) Then GoTo eexit
    exportDoc(s)
    workerThreadComplete
eexit:
    workerThreadComplete
End Sub
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of calling the label `eexit`, use square brackets to escape reserved words: `[exit]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of way:

```
Sub MainSub(params As Object) 'run by workerThread
    Dim s As sessionData = CType(params, sessionData)

    If (verifyExcelResource(s) AndAlso
        launchAS400(s) AndAlso
        runLookup(s) AndAlso
        payeeProcessLoop(s))
    Then
        exportDoc(s) 

    workerThreadComplete
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless I use the short-circuit AndAlso operator rather than And, won't this run all the subroutines even if the first returns false?

Comment: Yes, good catch. That would be better. If left side of predicate returns false it will not check others with AndAlso. I am not VB guy, sorry. Updated answer.